# Run a binary file via systemctl

Tags: ubuntu, services, binary, systemctl

I have a file named `MFBot_Konsole_x86_64` that I downloaded from a website, to run it I just type `./MFBot_Konsole_x86_64`.

The file location is: `/home/rafael/botShakes/`

The file is a binary file, for now I just have it running on a screen session, but this is unpratical, any way to have it running on a systemctl service?

I tried this unit:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Bot do Shakes

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/rafael/botShakes/MFBot_Konsole_x86_64

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Are you wanting to run this as a system or user service?

Comment: You did not tell us the location of `file`, but `file` is not mentioned at all in the code. Is this an error in the code or the question.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I want to run it as a system service

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I wll edit the locations of the file, please check the edited question

Comment: The problem is that you never mention the file-name in the code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor by puting the Full Path to the file in the 'ExecStart' doesn't that mean that the file will be ran? How should I edit it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to run a binary as service you can follow these steps:

Write a service file named `MFBot_Konsole.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=MFBot_Konsole
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/rafael/botShakes
ExecStart=/home/rafael/botShakes/MFBot_Konsole_x86_64
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=MFBot_Konsole
User=root
Group=root
Environment=PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/rafael/botShakes


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Change `Restart`, `User` & `Group` etc. to your needs..
- Place it at `/etc/systemd/system/MFBot_Konsole.service`
- Enable service via `systemctl enable MFBot_Konsole`
- Check if service started without errors via `systemctl status MFBot_Konsole`