# How to start the service in Linux

Tags: bash, services

I wrote such a tutorial script to run the service mysleep

The service just on the command start starts sleep 10d and on the command stop kills the process on its pid

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
start)
   echo Сервис mysleep был запущен &
   sleep 10d &
   echo $!>/var/run/mysleep.pid
   ;;
stop)
   kill `cat /var/run/mysleep.pid` &
   rm /var/run/mysleep.pid
   ;;
restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
status)
   if [ -e /var/run/mysleep.pid ]; then
      echo Сервис mysleep активен, его идентификатор равен `cat /var/run/mysleep.pid`
   else
      echo Сервис mysleep еще не был запущен
      exit 1
   fi
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

After running the command **service mysleep start**
I get an error **Failed to start mysleep.service: Unit mysleep.service not found.**

Comment: you need to enable the service and write a .service file, see (similar) -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625605/run-a-binary-file-via-systemctl/625670#625670

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely read it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854122/script-is-not-an-en-executable-regular-file it seemed to me a very useful link